# In scala, can a variable changed in a for-loop be used outside the loop?

Tags: scala, variables, for-loop

I'm updating a variable within a for-loop in scala that I need outside the loop. I tested the code below and got the message "ERROR: undefined". The variable is not empty, inside the loop the values are returned. Thank you.

```
val example=List(0,0,1,0.7,10,2,5,7,4,1,-9,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,-80,-6.6,-1,0)
var b=scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.empty[Double]
var b_val:Double=0

for (i<-1 to 24) {
    if ( example (i) != 0 ){b_val = b_val + example(i)} else {b_val = 0}
    b += b_val;
}
println(b);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? this type of code is strongly discourage in Scala

Comment: @Pavel - could you please elaborate? I need to calculate several sums of consecutives non-zero values based on a sequence of undisclosed zeros / non-zeros.

Comment: This code has no "undefined" error. It throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but that's easily fixed.

Comment: The code you give compiles fine and throws exception because is no `example(24)`. The answer to the question in the title is "yes, you can; but you very rarely should".

Comment: I would refer you to scala api on lists: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/List.html try use takeWhile, partion on any other build in functions

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because `example` only has `24` items. Therefore `example(i)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i` is `24`.

Comment: I changed the loop limit and it works fine now, thanks! Now, about your comment, what is the drawback on using the variable outside the loop?

Comment: There is no immediate drawback, however if you want to be more Scala idiomatic you would rewrite the whole loop to be immutable instead (i.e. swap out the `var`s for `val`s and use immutable collections)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add `b_val` which is double to `AnyVal` which won't work.

So, to add you need to cast the elements in List to Double as below or define `example` as `List[Double]`, also your iteration won't work because you are doing `to 24` which will blow up because list indexes from `0 to 23`

```
    val example = List(0, 0, 1, 0.7, 10, 2, 5, 7, 4, 1, -9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, -80, -6.6, -1, 0)
    var b = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.empty[Double]
    var b_val: Double = 0

    for (i <- 0 until example.length) {

      if (example(i) != 0) {
        b_val = (b_val + example(i).asInstanceOf[Double])
      } else {
        b_val = 0
      }
      b += b_val
    }
    println(b)
```

Result is : `MutableList(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.7, 11.7, 13.7, 18.7, 25.7, 29.7, 30.7, 21.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -80.0, -86.6, -87.6, 0.0)`

But only you know what you are trying to achieve, small refactor I would do to it in scala way

```
val example = List(0, 0, 1, 0.7, 10, 2, 5, 7, 4, 1, -9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, -80, -6.6, -1, 0)

var b = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.empty[Double]

var b_val: Double = 0

example.foreach(elem => {
  if (elem != 0) {
    b_val = b_val + elem.asInstanceOf[Double]
  } else {
    b_val = 0
  }
  b += b_val
})

println(b)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply; however, changing only the indexes worked.

Comment: you mean you tried `0 to 23`? didn't you have to do `example(i).asInstanceOf[Double]` as well? Also, go with `example.foreach{}` so that it looks nicer and is a scala way.

Comment: No, I kept the same definition and is now ok. Thank you for the scala way example (this is my first exercise in scala!).

Comment: @Sandra What is same definition? It can be made even nicer with `.map` but your algorithm is not quite clear.

Comment: I mean I changed only the indexes (to 0 and 23). I think it works because `b` is defined as a list of doubles. Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll check how to use `.map` here.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for something like this:

```
 val b = example.scanLeft(0.0) {
    case (_, 0) => 0
    case (l, r) => l + r
 }
```

If you are going to be writing scala code anyway, learn to do it in scala way. There is no point otherwise.